# circular imports with webpack returning empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Hitting this exact problem currently:

```
FileA:
var b = require file B
var c = require file C

FileB:
var a = require file A

FileC:
var a = require file A
```

When I run the code, I get an error in File C:

```
A.doSomething is not a function
```

Threw a debugger in there and saw that A is an empty object. What's **really** weird is that I'm only getting an error in File C, but not File B. Super confused here.

Comment: I wrote a tool to check your Webpack project for circular dependencies: https://github.com/DelvarWorld/webpack-cyclic-dependency-checker

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is not a webpack issue but a property of CommonJS modules.

When a CommonJS module is first required, its `exports` property is initialized to an empty object behind the scenes.

```js
module.exports = {};
```

The module can then decide to extend this `exports` property, or override it.

```js
exports.namedExport = function() { /* ... */ }; // extends

module.exports = { namedExport: function() { /* ... */ } }; // overrides
```

So when `A` requires `B` and `B` requires `A` right after, `A` is not executed again (which would produce an infinite loop), but its current `exports` property is returned. Since `A` required `B` at the very top of the file, before exporting anything, the `require('A')` call in the `B` module will yield an empty object.

A common fix for circular dependencies is to put your imports at the end of the file, **after** you've exported the variables needed by other modules.

`A`:

```js
module.exports = { foo: 'bar' };
require('B'); // at this point A.exports is not empty anymore
```

`B`:

```js
var A = require('A');
A.foo === 'bar';
```

Comment: hey you :) thanks it helped me understand the problem. But what if in A, you need access to some attribute exported by B? In my codebase I just replaced `module.exports` by `exports.attribute` and it now works but it feels not very natural

Comment: You can always do the same thing in B. `module.exports = { bar: 'foo' }; var A = require('a');`, then `module.exports = { foo: 'bar' }; var B = require('B');`. If your exports depend on each other, then you should build them progressively by extending `exports` instead of overriding it.

Comment: This is the most important answer ever given on Stack Overflow. And you are a hero.

Comment: Saved my bacon. Thx!

Comment: We have this problem and this answer solves it but does not work when we do our mocha build. :(