# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid (react, webpack, circular imports)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export, webpack, require

First of all I want to say that I'm new to javascript and react world so sorry in advance if my question is trivial but I can't figure out this situation. I will update the post if needed. 

I want to migrate my current application to single page application. I have 3 main pages PageA, PageB and PageC (in react I have 3 main components). I want to be able to switch between these 3 pages/components. Lets say that I have this LogoText which is the component that represents the logo of the site. I want to have it in all other components (including the PageA) and when I click on it I want to render the main page ( PageA ).


So I'm trying to build a it with **react** and **webpack** . In this simple example given below I have a main page component MainPage.js which is parent component for all components that should be in the main page and a LogoText component which should render the MainPage component when someone click on it. When all this components are in one file and I don't use **require()** everything is working perfectly but when I break down my app into modules using **require()** and package it with **webpack** I get strange behaviour. I can load the MainPage component and the LogoText component is displayed correctly in the MainPage but when I click on the LogoText I get "**Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid**" exception ([click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PkqI.jpg))


**first exception**: 
react.js:18798 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

**second exception**: 
react.js:18354 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I have the following 3 classes:

main.js:

```
var MainPage = require("./MainPage.js")

ReactDOM.render(
   <MainPage />,
   document.getElementById('content')
);
```

MainPage.js:

```
var LogoText = require("./LogoText.js")

var MainPage = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello page,
                <LogoText />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = MainPage;
```

LogoText.js

```
var MainPage = require("./MainPage.js")

var LogoText = React.createClass({

    changePage: function(e) {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <MainPage />,
            document.getElementById('content')
        );
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <span onClick={this.changePage}>logo</span>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = LogoText;
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="scripts/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 1**:
Here is my **webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/scripts/main.js",
    output: {
        path: "./src/scripts",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'},
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        //don't bundle the 'react' npm package with our bundle.js
        //but get it from a global 'React' variable
        'react': 'React'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```

Comment: post the webpack.config.js, I dont see an obvious error in the react code

Comment: I have updated the post pasting my "webpack.config.js" file content

Comment: ReactDOM.render should not be in LogoText. You are not "thinking in React."

Comment: Yup missed that one, thats no good..

Comment: Ok then how should I render the MainPage from the LogoText ? I have tried rendering another pages with ReactDOM.render in the exact same way  and it is working. There is a problem only in this case. I can guess that it is because of the circular require()

Comment: What are you trying top achieve with the 'changePage' method of LogoText?

Comment: I want to migrate my current application to single page application. I have 3 main pages PageA, PageB and PageC (in react I have 3 main components). I want to be able to switch between these 3 pages/components. Lets say that I have this LogoText which is the component that represents the logo of the site. I want to have it in all other components (including the PageA) and when I click on it I want to render the main page ( PageA ).

Comment: Also I forgot to say that when every component is in one file and I don't use require (webpack) everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok obviously my intuition was correct **"I can guess that it is because of the circular require()"**. The answer is here : "[circular imports with webpack returning empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378226/circular-imports-with-webpack-returning-empty-object)".

I think that [**react router**](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) will be the correct way to implement this. I will try it and I will post the results here later :)

**UPDATE 1:**
React router is exactly what I'm searching for. [This is the exact tutorial that solved my problem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/12-navigating).