# Webpack3: require inside exported module not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs, webpack-3

When trying to access a module I created `util.js` inside of a file where I use `module.exports` in webpack, it results in an empty object at build time. In the image below, my `const utils = require(...)` returns an empty object.

[image]

However, when I inspect my `const utils = require(...)` inside of my main script `background-script.js` , which doesn't use a module.exports, it's defined.

[image]

**Problem**
Webpack doesn't seem to be resolving the `require`'s inside the modules I'm using i'm exporting.

**Project File Structure**

```
  app
  ├──plugins
  │   ├── index.js (exports all my plugins)
  |   ├──plugin1
  |   │   ├── index.js (simply exports an object)
  |   |
  |   |──plugin2
  |       ├── index.js (simply exports an object)
  |
  |--utils.js
  |--background-script.js
```

**app/background-script.js**

```
  const utils = require('../../util.js');
```

**app/utils.js**

```
  const utils ={....};
  utils.plugins = require('./plugins/index.js');
  module.exports = utils;
```

**plugins/index.js**

```
  //require all `index.js` file from each plugin directory; works great.
  const context = require.context('.', true, /index\.js/);
  const requireAllPlugins = function(ctx) {
    const keys = ctx.keys();
    const values = keys.map(ctx);
    return values;
  }
  const allPlugins = requireAllPlugins(context);
  module.exports = [...allPlugins];
```

**plugin1/index.js**

```
  //utils is an empty object
  const utils = require('../../util.js');
  module.exports = {action: utils.renderBookmark}
```

Comment: have you tried `'../../../util.js'`?

Comment: That doesn't work & shouldn't since that would take me out of my app folder. I' m going to look into webpack's `resolve` property & `output.library` properties later today. I'll be back

Answer (score 0):

**Answering my own question**

Turns out the reason why my `const utils = require('../../utils.js')` inside `app/plugins/plugin1/index.js` was returning an empty object was because I had a circular/cyclic dependency defined.
Basically, I was creating an infinite loop with the way I was requiring my
modules.
NodeJS handles in a very specific way; it returns an empty object. See this Stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378226/circular-imports-with-webpack-returning-empty-object)

```
  //app/background-script.js 
  const utils = require('../../util.js');
    |
    |
    ↓
  //app/utils.js
  const utils = {...}
  utils.plugins = require('./plugins/index.js');
    |
    |
    ↓
    //app/plugins/index.js
    const context = require.context('.', true, /index\.js/);
    const requireAllPlugins = function(ctx) {
      const keys = ctx.keys();
      const values = keys.map(ctx);
      return values;
    }
    const allPlugins = requireAllPlugins(context);
    module.exports = [...allPlugins];
    |
    |
    ↓
    //plugins/plugin1/index.js
    const utils = require('../../util.js'); 
    |    module.exports = {action: utils.renderBookmark}
    |
    ↓
  // app/utils.js
  const utils = {...}
      utils.plugins = require('./plugins/index.js'); //restarts the calls above again.
    |
    |
    ↓ Node detected a circular dependency, so instead of repeating these calls again, forever, return `{}` instead. This `{}` will become the
    value of `utils` inside `plugins/plugin1/index.js`
```

Circular dependencies usually are a result of bad code organization. To solve my issue, I removed

```
`require('./plugins/index.js');` from utils
```

This npm module [webpack-cyclic-dependency-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cyclic-dependency-checker) helped me find the cyclic dependency after I started sensing I had a cyclic dependency somewhere in my codebase.